# Remix: Won't stop preserving state through rerouting to a nested route of the same Dynamic Segment

Tags: state, nested-routes, remix.run

It may be because I'mm using 2 dynamic segments in a row, but i cant modify the database so I have to work around that.

Example: using V2_routing btw

```
~/routes/example.$id.$id2.jsx

import { useLoaderData, useParams } from "@remix-run/react";
import { json } from "@remix-run/node";
import { getExample } from "~/models/example.server.js;

export const loader = async ({params}) => {
   return json({ example: await getExample(params.id)});
};

export default function Example() {
   let { id2 } = useParams();
   let { example } = useLoaderData();

   return (
      <div>
         <p>{`${ id2 === "0" ? example.one : example.two }'}</p>
      </div>
   )
}
```

Theres times and things that will rerender when you navigate from say "/example/abc/1" to "/example/def/0" but many things won't. Specifically  tags and defaultValues on an input.

I've tried initializing example to any empty object then setting it with useLoaderData.
Thought I'd check if anyone had had this problem before I went insane trying to get state off the remix api with useEffect/fetch or trying to combine state management with the loader function.

Comment: So i figured a few things out, most of the problems are fixed by concatenating the two dynamic segments ($id& + $id2) then substringing them back apart.

That fixed everything but the Audio tag, which in react doesn't automatically change with a state change. Still figuring that out, the useRef hook didnt seems to fix it.